# apigee edge platform: two way ssl

Tags: apigee

I am trying to evaluate the apigee edge platform. Is it possible to have two way ssl between api consumer and apigee server (this is a special case for us, though it does not make much sense in API world).

Thanks.

Comment: can it be more specific? mind telling us what have you tried so far?It might helps us to give better answer in your context.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible.  You configure the `VirtualHost` much like the `TargetEndpoint` mentioned [in the apigee docs](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/client-ssl-backend-servers).  If you're a cloud customer(free or paid), you'll need to reach out to Apigee's support team as the virtual host configurations in the cloud are locked down.

Example config of `VirtualHost` (uses same `<SSLInfo>` config as `TargetEndpoint`):

```
<VirtualHost name="secure">
    <HostAliases>
        <HostAlias>myOrg-test.apigee.net</HostAlias>
    </HostAliases>
    <Port>443</Port>
    <SSLInfo>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <ClientAuthEnabled>true</ClientAuthEnabled>
        <IgnoreValidationErrors>false</IgnoreValidationErrors>
        <KeyAlias>myKeyAlias</KeyAlias>
        <KeyStore>myKeystore</KeyStore>
        <TrustStore>myTruststore</TrustStore>
    </SSLInfo>
</VirtualHost>
```